# Spring data MongoDB Geo-spatial queries with multiple criteria

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I'm using spring data mongodb 2.2.4 and I'm trying to get paginated documents as GeoPage near a given point with multiple criteria.

Using geo spatial queries seems to not be working as expected as the request is not generated correctly:

```
findByLocationNearAndCategories(Point point, Distance distance, String category, Pageable pageable)
```

=>

```
[{ "$geoNear" : { "query" : { "categories" : { "x" : 3.8235442, "y" : 43.5833389}}, "maxDistance" : 0.1567855942887398, "distanceMultiplier" : 6378.137, "near" : [3.8235442, 43.5833389], "spherical" : true, "distanceField" : "dis"}}, { "$limit" : 4}]
```

or

```
findByCategoriesAndLocationNear(String category, Point point, Distance distance, Pageable pageable)
```

=>

```
[{ "$geoNear" : { "query" : { "categories" : "myCategory", "location" : { "$nearSphere" : { "x" : 3.8235442, "y" : 43.5833389}, "$maxDistance" : 0.1567855942887398}}, "maxDistance" : 0.1567855942887398, "distanceMultiplier" : 6378.137, "near" : [3.8235442, 43.5833389], "spherical" : true, "distanceField" : "dis"}}, { "$limit" : 4}]
```

that results in error 'Too many geoNear expressions'.

I've tried using MongoOperations but I'm only able to get GeoResults instead of paginated results using GeoPage.

```
GeoResults<MyClass> result = mongoOperations.query(MyClass.class)
                .as(MyClass.class)                          
                .near(NearQuery.near(point)
                        .maxDistance(distance)
                        .query(new Query(Criteria.where("categories").is("myCategory")))
                        .with(page))
                .all()
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm managing this for now by making a second requests to get the total count but I'm expecting to implement this in a optimized way.

```
GeoResults<MyClass> geoResults = mongoOperations.query(MyClass.class)
  .as(MyClass.class)                          
  .near(NearQuery.near(point)
    .maxDistance(distance)
    .query(new Query(Criteria.where("categories").is("myCategory")))
    .with(page))
  .all();
        
long count = mongoOperations.count(new Query(Criteria.where("categories").is("myCategory").and("location").near(point).maxDistance(distance.getValue())), MyClass.class);
        
return new GeoPage<MyClass>(geoResults, page, count);
```

Comment: Same problem here.